# Material Design <select> not populating after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design

I need to populate a select menu after an AJAX request, but it not working...

Let´s see some code:

```
<th>
   <select id="selectEstado">
       <option value="-1" disabled selected>Selecione o Estado</option>
          @foreach ($estados as $uf)
              <option value="{{ $uf->UF }}">{{ $uf->nome }}</option>
          @endforeach
    </select>
</th>
<th>
    <select id="select-rm">
       <option value="-1" selected>Região Metropolitana</option>
    </select>
</th>
```

The #selectEstado changes, jQuery listen to and calls the AJAX request:

```
    var uf = $(this).val();
    $("#select-rm").find('option').not(':first').remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/pegaRM/" + uf,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
            var len = response.length;
            if (len > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    var id = response[i].UF;
                    var name = response[i].municipio;
                    var option = "<option value='" + id + "'>" + name + "</option>";
                    $('#select-rm').append(option);
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Then at the  part of the code, everything works great, but the material design part doesn't:

```
     <input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger" type="text" readonly="true" data-target="select-options-636d5143-d4a6-f10d-4ee2-818e0d36044c">
       <ul id="select-options-636d5143-d4a6-f10d-4ee2-818e0d36044c" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" tabindex="0" style="">
          <li id="select-options-636d5143-d4a6-f10d-4ee2-818e0d36044c0" tabindex="0" class="selected"><span>Região Metropolitana</span>
          </li>
       </ul>
       <svg class="caret" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
       </svg>
         <select id="select-rm" tabindex="-1">
                <option value="-1" selected="">Região Metropolitana</option>
                <option value="AM">Alvarães</option>
                <option value="AM">Amaturá</option>
                <option value="AM">Anamã</option>
                ...
          </select>
  </div>
...
```

---

Editing:

At the console/network tab, the answer comes as:

```
[{"id":152,"UF":"AM","nome":"","UFMunCod":1300029,"municipio":"Alvar\u00e3es","populacao":"16.041"},{"id":153,"UF":"AM","nome":"","UFMunCod":1300060,"municipio":"Amatur\u00e1","populacao":"11.536"},{"id":154,"UF":"AM","nome":"","UFMunCod":1300086,"municipio":"Anam\u00e3","populacao":"13.614"},{"id":155,"UF":"AM","nome":"","UFMunCod":1300102,"municipio":"Anori","populacao":"21.010"},{"id":156,"UF":"AM","nome":"","UFMunCod":1300144,"municipio":"Apu\u00ed","populacao":"21.973"},
...
```

The HTML select is populating, but the *material design* doesn´t.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example/sample of `response` at this point `success: function (response) {`?

Comment: Dear @freedomn-m, the ```success: ``` is there, right above the 'POST' method. Is that all You need?

Answer (score 0):

Done!
I´ve added the code
`$('#select-rm').formSelect();`
after `$('#select-rm').append(option);` and it is working good!

Thanks you guys!